# Copy TFS Collection to another collection

Tags: tfs, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I am trying to merge all my TFS Projects into a single project, as recommended.

However, all the tools seem pre TFS 11 (2012), and haven't been updated since.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: It doesn't look like they have anything yet. Why not do the upgrade,  create a new team project for all of the code and then branch everything in from the old to the new?

Comment: Can you branch between collections!?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Do you have more than one collection? If you can setup a test environment you might try the integration tools from 2012 and see how it goes. I wouldn't do it on production until practicing first though.

Comment: We have many collections (as per team/company), but within a single collection many projects, we wish to take many projects to one, for a given single collection

Comment: I dont think you can go cross collection but you can definitely create a new team project and branch from the others into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TFS Integration Tool](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) can helps you. It works fine with TFS2013 for workitem and source control migration.

Comment: Doesn't it require the 2008 libs?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar As I know it requires TFS 2010 client libs.

Comment: This worked ! We have now moved all our Source and Work Items to a new collection

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to integrate only the source code of multiple team projects into a team projects with in single collection then you can use **Move** version control operations to move source code.

If you want to migrate work items as well then you need to use TFS Integration tools.